# At design time, can you prevent components from moving on the first selection click?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

All of our forms tend to have things get a few pixels out of place because when we click a component to modify the properties, there is a tendency to have the component move if the mouse is still moving the tiniest bit when we select a component.

Is there a setting that makes it so you can't move a component that isn't already selected? (Requiring a second intentinoal click to actually move things.)

Comment: There is an entry in the Edit menu to fix the elements, but that means they are really fixed.

Comment: To avoid the tiny movement you can enable grid alignment in the Form Designer options.

Comment: ...we can only hope for : http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2747

Comment: Let me guess. You aren't using revision control?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Even still... using revision control to implement `Ctrl-Z` is a bit like using cluster bombs as insect repellent.  The real travesty here is that we still don't have 'undo' in the forms designer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's annoying, even with revision control. I sometimes work through RDP and there it happens frequently. OP, I usually use the drag selection or the structure viewer to avoid this sort of thing from happening.

Comment: I agree. It's annoying. But it is what it is. So use the revision control system as back stop.

Comment: For me it started with Delphi 2007.  It was fine before.  Now I am scared to double click on any component.  So, I think it can be fixed.

Comment: @UweRaabe I have always had that on 8, but it does nothing to prevent the problem.  Yes it is also ticked.  :-)

Comment: This should be posted as a feature request in the Embarcadero Quality Portal

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - We are using version control, but once it is noticed, it's easier to just realign it manually than revert the file.  "It is what it is" isn't a great answer to annoying software design.

Comment: Well, it is what it is. Nobody here can fix it for you. Did you contact Emba?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable "Lock controls" from the "Edit" menu, then it won't move when you click it, but it will of course remain locked also at the second click. 
However, at least it will save you from the accidental moves just because you need to select the control

Comment: This has been buggy for over ten years! Even when locked, the Lock will not be persistent between sessions and even between loadings of the project! I've tried to tell that Embarcadero many times but it does not help!

Answer (score 1):

I find uncheck (use designer guidline) can prevent the problem,
but you will not see the alignment line.

tools->options->Form Designer